# matlab app plot creates an 3D plot when a standard 2d plot is expected

Tags: matlab, plot

I created a matlab app using their app builder and play with an Axis inside this App.

This is the Axis

> this.currentAxes
>
> UIAxes with properties:
>
> ```
>          XLim: [0 4000]
>          YLim: [-5 20]
>        XScale: 'linear'
>        YScale: 'linear'
> GridLineStyle: '-'
>      Position: [31 15 738 409]
>         Units: 'pixels'
> ```

and I try to plot a vector with dimensions 3571x1

```
hplot(1) = plot(this.currentAxes, this.results.targetPos);
```

I expect a 2D plot, but the result is a 3D plot. I have no idea why this happens and how to prevent it.
Sorry for not providing a small example. I took all code from an old guide App and made it run in the new classes.

[image: App Screenhot]

EDIT: Minimal Example

The code generated by the App Designer seems to be the cause of the problem

```
% code generated by app Designer
fig = uifigure;
ax = uiaxes(fig);
title(ax, 'Title')
xlabel(ax, 'X')
ylabel(ax, 'Y')
zlabel(ax, 'Z')
ax.CameraPosition = [0.5 0.5 9];
ax.CameraViewAngle = 0;
ax.DataAspectRatio = [1 1 1];
ax.PlotBoxAspectRatio = [1.5 1 1];
ax.Position = [31 46 738 378];

% my code
% fixes the problem
% ax.CameraPosition = [0 0 100];
x = linspace(-pi,pi,50);
y = 5*sin(x);
plot(ax,x,y)
```

Comment: Without a MCVE it's difficult to say why this happens. As a workaround, can you use [`view(2)`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html) to force the plot to be viewed along the Z-axis?

Comment: Indeed view(2) restores a 2d view. But the DisplayRatio is set to 'equal' or similar, since the y axis is only 1/100 of the size of the x-axis. But I want the axis to be filled in both dimensions.

Comment: Add an `axis square` after the `view(2)`?

Comment: That works, also axis normal. But it only works after the second plot. It seems it needs to get a replot command or similar to apply it.